Rule of thumb for triangle strips vs indexed tris for terrain?
I'm working on procedural generation for my game.
I plan to have a lot of geometry detail, and so I'm trying to build for optimal performance from the ground up
Essentially I'll have 9 + 8N chunks, where N is the render distance (3x3 high-res chunks, then 8 chunks surrounding them at 3x scale, etc.)
I'm starting with a chunk height map resolution of 256x256, so about 130,000 tris per chunk, or roughly 500k tris rendered at a given time with a render distance of 1 with the off-screen chunks culled
From some research, I'm seeing people say that triangle strips have been obsolete for a couple decades, and one should opt for indexed triangles as they have better cache performance. However in this case where I'm working with a handful of meshes all with different vertex data but hundreds of thousands of vertices a piece, it seems like triangle strips would make up any loss from cache misses by the sheer number of redundant data I don't have to keep around
Any insight into this is appreciated.
Fyi I'm asking before I build either option just in case there's an obvious answer. Naturally I'll benchmark my solution once implemented to make sure performance is acceptable.

Why don't you create this terrain that you're talking about and try each method and see which one has better performance? Just generate a large terrain mesh in something like Blender and render that, shouldn't take long at all.

Something to watch for with your proposed grid subdivision: when the player moves one high-res chunk to the East, you have to re-generate all the low-res chunks because they no longer match up to the grid centered on this new chunk. That's why many games use powers of two for their chunk divisions, so you still align to the same grid after a move, and can re-use more of your chunks, only having to generate what's genuinely new (previously unseen at this resolution).

@DMGregory good callout. I've been thinking about how to mitigate this, and having a quadtree style 4x4 hi-res inner square surrounded by concentric 12 squares at half res and so on makes a bit more sense. More overall high-res meshes, but would also make better use of culling. My particular game is not open world and the player has limited mobility, so it might not actually be a huge issue, but they will certainly travel at least a few chunks away from the origin
